# How can I get the IUnknown* pointer (if any) for some Visual Basic 6 control?

Tags: c, windows, com, vb6

I'd like to call some C functions from a Visual Basic 6 program which take an `IUnknown*`. Assuming that I know that some control in my VB6 application is an ActiveX control, can I get the underlying `IUnknown*` out of that (maybe by casting?) to pass it to the C function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*All* COM interfaces derive from `IUnknown`, you can just use the `IUnknown` methods on any valid interface pointer.

If you need an additional reference to the same component, but don't care about which interface then use the `QueryInterface` method for `IUknown`.

Comment: I may be missing something here, but - how can I call `QueryInterface` on some Visual Basic object *in Visual Basic*? I tried doing `Set o = CreateObject("COMCTL.Slider")` but the returned object (calling `TypeName()` on it yields `Slider` so the object appears to be valid) doesn't support a `QueryInterface` method.

Comment: @Frerich: Implicit type casts in vb6 are calls to QueryInterface. (`set o2 = o1` will call `QueryInterface` on `o1` for `o2`'s type.) And remember in VB6 `IUnknown` is called `Object` (with some limitations: in practice much easier to work with `IDispatch`).

Comment: Ah, that's interesting. However, how could I get the raw pointer value of that (so that I could pass it to a C function which expects to take an `IUnknown*`)? I tried calliny my C function with `ObjPtr(o2)` (where `o2` is some `Object`) and then casting the `long` in the C code to `IUnknown*` but that didn't quite work. Actually, now that I think about it, maybe `ObjPtr(o1)` actually yields an `IUnknown**`? Hmm...

Comment: @Frerich: For a COM interface just pass it. For a direct API call: not sure (its been too long since I did any serious VB6 interop). Perhaps asking that specific question directly here will elicit an answer (include C definition of the API if possible).

Answer (score 1):

One interesting thing I found out in the meanwhile (just mentioning it in case somebody finds this question): for many controls I tested, the `GWL_USERDATA` value returned by `GetWindowLong` yields the address of some struct which has the `IUnknown` pointer value at offset 12. So the following may work for you:

```
IUnknown *unk = (IUnknown *)((char*)GetWindowLong( hwnd, GWL_USERDATA ) + 12);
```

It seems many controls have the same struct stored at the address given by `GWL_USERDATA`. Maybe it's true for all Visual Basic controls or so?